# I have to make a hangman game TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Tags: python

I have to make a hangman game for school and I keep getting errors at line 95:

> TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable.

The program takes a file with words with spaces between (the words in english small letters)
You have 8 tries to guess it. I know the code isn't good but I'm just starting.

```
import sys #Exit from Python. This is implemented by raising the SystemExit exception, so cleanup actions specified by finally clauses of try statements are honored, and it is possible to intercept the exit attempt at an outer level.
#all imported library
(flile_path, index) = (input("wat is the words list file path?"), (int(input("what is the location of your word?")) - 1))
def choose_word():
 with open(flile_path) as file:
    return([tuple(map(str, i.split(' '))) for i in file][0][int(index)])
#impport the file
old_guess = 0
unguessed_parts =[]
MAX_TRIES = 8
SECRET_WORD = choose_word()
print(SECRET_WORD)
#definition of all the veriabels
HANGMAN_PHOTOS = { \
    "picture_1": """ x-------x """ \
    , "picture_2": """
    x-------x
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
""" \
    , "picture_3": """
    x-------x
    |       |
    |       0
    |
    |
    |
""" \
    , "picture_4": """
    x-------x
    |       |
    |       0
    |       |
    |
    |
""" \
    , "picture_5": """
    x-------x
    |       |
    |       0
    |      /|
    |
    |
""" \
    , "picture_6": """
    x-------x
    |       |
    |       0
    |      /|\ 
    |      
    |
""" \
    , "picture_7": """
    x-------x
    |       |
    |       0
    |      /|\ 
    |      /
    |
""" \
    , "picture_8": """
    x-------x
    |       |
    |       0
    |      /|\ 
    |      / \ 
    |
"""}
HANGMAN_ASCII_ART = """
  _    _                                         
 | |  | |                                        
 | |__| | __ _ _ __   __ _ _ __ ___   __ _ _ __  
 |  __  |/ _` | '_ \ / _` | '_ ` _ \ / _` | '_ \ 
 | |  | | (_| | | | | (_| | | | | | | (_| | | | |
 |_|  |_|\__,_|_| |_|\__, |_| |_| |_|\__,_|_| |_|
                      __/ |                      
                     |___/
 """
print(HANGMAN_ASCII_ART, "you'r maximum tries is: ", MAX_TRIES)
for unguessed_parts_count in range(0, len(SECRET_WORD)):
    unguessed_parts += ["_ "]
print(''.join(unguessed_parts))


# all verbs def is up

def Main():
    global old_guess, SECRET_WORD, unguessed_parts, right_latters
    guess = input("what is your guess?").lower()

    def check_valid_input(letter_guessed, old_letters):
        if len(letter_guessed) == 1 and letter_guessed.isalpha() and not letter_guessed in old_letters:
            return (True)
        else:
            return (False)

    def show_hidden_word(secret_word, last_guess):
        global unguessed_parts, right_latters_count
        for latter in secret_word:
            if latter in last_guess:
                unguessed_parts[secret_word.index(latter)] = latter
                print(''.join(unguessed_parts))
                right_latters_count += 1
                return ()
        print(right_latters_count, len(old_guess))
        print_hangman(len(old_guess) - right_latters_count)
        print(''.join(unguessed_parts))

    def print_hangman(misstakes):
        global HANGMAN_PHOTOS
        print(str(HANGMAN_PHOTOS["picture_" + str(misstakes)]))

    while check_valid_input(guess, old_guess) == False:
        print("X")
        guess = input("what is your new guess?").lower()
    old_guess += (guess)
    show_hidden_word(SECRET_WORD, guess)


for trie_num in range(0, MAX_TRIES):
    Main()
    if right_latters_count == len(SECRET_WORD):
        print('you won! the word is: ', SECRET_WORD)
        sys.exit()
    elif MAX_TRIES == (len(old_guess) - right_latters_count):
        print("you lose: ")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("your old guesses: ", old_guess)
        continue
```

Comment: Please see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question, [ask].

Comment: Which is line 95?

Comment: @ScottHunter `if len(letter_guessed) == 1 and letter_guessed.isalpha() and not letter_guessed in old_letters`

Comment: The problem is that `old_guess` is defined as 0, which is an `int`. It looks like it should be a list.